# pecl_http add post request body in hotelbeds apitude

Tags: php, xml, pecl

Recently I started working with [hotelbeds apitude PHP API](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/Home)

I am trying to add `xml` code to a `POST` request body using `pecl_http`. I tried with following code -

```
$xml_part = <<< EOD
                <<<XML PART>>> EOD;

$request = new http\Client\Request("POST",
                    $endpoint,
                    ["Api-Key" => $hotel_beds_config['api_key'],
                        "X-Signature" => $signature,
                        "Content-Type" => "application/xml",
                        "Accept" => "application/xml"],
                    $xml_part
                );
```

I got the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to http\Client\Request::__construct() must be an instance of http\Message\Body, string 
>   given

Then I tried with following code -

```
$request = new http\Client\Request("POST",
                    $endpoint,
                    ["Api-Key" => $hotel_beds_config['api_key'],
                        "X-Signature" => $signature,
                        "Content-Type" => "application/xml",
                        "Accept" => "application/xml"],
                    new http\Message\Body($xml_part)
```

Now I get following error -

> Fatal error: Uncaught http\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: http\Message\Body::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

I get the documentation to add body message here -

[pecl_http](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Message/Body)

How can I add the xml code to the `POST` request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`http\Message\Body::__construct()` constructor documentation](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Message/Body/__construct), the single parameter it optionally accepts is a stream or file handle resource (as in `fopen()`). It does not directly accept string data as you ave provided in `$xml_part`.

Instead, pecl http provides [an `append()` method](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Message/Body/append) on the `Body` class which you should be able to use to append the XML onto the empty body.  So start by creating a `Body` object in a variable, then append your XML onto it. Finally, pass the `Body` object into your `Request` object.

```
// Create a Body object first, with no argument
$body = new http\Message\Body();
// Append your XML to it
$body->append($xml_part);

// Create the Request and pass $body to it
$request = new http\Client\Request("POST",
                $endpoint,
                ["Api-Key" => $hotel_beds_config['api_key'],
                    "X-Signature" => $signature,
                    "Content-Type" => "application/xml",
                    "Accept" => "application/xml"],
                // Pass in $body
                $body
            );

// Create an \http\Client object, enqueue, and send the request...
$client = new \http\Client();
// Set options as needed for your application...
$client->enqueue($request);
$client->send();
```

#### Addendum: Why not use the SDK?

The API you are attempting to POST to [provides a PHP SDK](https://github.com/hotelbeds-sdk/hotel-api-sdk-php/blob/master/README.md). If the SDK supports the Availability function you are hoping to use, perhaps it would be simpler to use it rather than pecl_http (which has limited documentation).  The SDK would then abstract all of the HTTP messaging into a series of PHP methods and properties, eliminating any doubt on the proper construction of POST requests.

Comment: Yes, the error is fixed. But I get response body is empty. May be it can't process xml code.

Response code is 200

Comment: I cannot really assist with that, because I don't know anything about what endpoint you are using or what its requirements are or expected response. If it returns a 200, for a well-behaved API that usually indicates success.  But as far as what you initially asked about, it sounds like your pecl http client is now indeed sending a POST request (assuming $xml_part is an XML string).

Comment: That's correct. Your answer solved the issue. :)

One thing, does message body can take xml string? Do I need to change any conversion to string?

Last time I sent HTTP request through Wordpress HTTP_API. Then it also gave 200 response but with empty response body.

Comment: A POST or response body can consist of only an XML string, if that is what is expected by the endpoint. In other cases, it is possible that the endpoint may expect form fields, where the XML is encoded as a field value, but a raw XML (or JSON) body is probably more common for a well structured API.

Comment: Actually I am working on this part - https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/apitude_booking/Availability

But every time get empty body with 200 response

Comment: According to [their error documentation](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/APITUDE_for_Activities_ERRORS) a 200 should only indicate success. How are you attempting to read the response body to verify it is empty? And did you attempt to test the POST request outside of PHP using Postman [as recommended](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/Home)? If you omit the body (`$xml_part = ""`) or deliberately send malformed XML, do you get a non-200 response? These are the things you should attempt to test.

Comment: Failing that, contact the support team for that API.